# stack using linked lists in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

anybody please can help me with this little problem I'm having ?
I'm trying to implement a stack using linked lists in c++. 
The program should display the elements of the stack when I enter end, but the program is just outputting the last element I have entered, and whenever I enter pop the program is ignoring my first pushed element.
the program should push and pop by commands from stranded input, such as (push 2, push 1, pop, peek or end) 
any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    };

public:
    node* top;
    Stack()
    {
        top = NULL;
    }

    void push(int n)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = NULL;
        top = temp;
    }

    int pop()
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        return temp->data;
    }

    int peek()
    {
         return top-> data;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return top == NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack stack;

    std::string command;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "stack>";
        std::cin >> command;
        try
        {
            if (command == "pop")
            {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("error: stack is empty");
                }
                std::cout << stack.pop() << std::endl;
            }

            else if (command == "push")
            {
                int n;
                if (!(std::cin >> n))
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("error: not a number");
                }
                stack.push(n);
            }

            else if (command == "peek")
            {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("error: stack is empty");
                }
                std::cout << stack.peek() << std::endl;
            }

            else if (command == "end")
            {
                while (!(stack.isEmpty()))
                {
                    std::cout << stack.pop() << std::endl;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("error: invalid command");
            }
         }
         catch (std::runtime_error& e)
         {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cerr << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you are leaking nodes every time you `pop`. c++ doesn't have garbage collection, you need to `delete` anything you `new`.

Comment: At no point do you ever set a node's `next` to anything but `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `push`

```
    void push(int n)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = NULL;
        top = temp;  // At this point, you have forgotten about the old value of top
    }
```

It should be:

```
    void push(int n)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = top; // Link rest of stack in
        top = temp; 
    }
```

You also have a memory leak in `pop`, and you need a destructor, a copy constructor, and a copy assignment operator in `stack` (the last two can just be deleted if you don't want to write them).